# How I fix this problem Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean?

Tags: php, database

I want to select all data for posts table according to department I tried to use this code but I got this error
Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean 
this is my code

```
    <?php
              if(isset($_GET['dept_n']))
              { 
                $de_id = $_GET['dept_n'];

              $sql = 'SELECT * FROM [posts WHERE dept_id = $de_id';
             $result = $connection->query($sql);

              $rows = $result->fetch_all();
              foreach($rows as $row)
              {
                $id = $row[0];
         echo"   <img src='./images/$row[3].jpg' style='width: 90%; height: 200px; '> 
            <h4 >$row[1]</h4>
}}?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us what did you tryed?

Comment: Your query failed. Most likely because of the typo here: `[posts`

Comment: *"Call to a member function fetchAll()"* - That isn't in your code. You have a mysqli_ function and not PDO.

Comment: @aynber I was going to mention the extra bracket too but you got there first :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all why you have bracket here?

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM [posts WHERE dept_id = $de_id';
```

You dont have to use foreach. Use while loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo $row[“name of column”];
}
```

Comment: And you missing quotes after echo in your code.

Comment: I tried to use as you said but still the same problem